# Discrete Choice modelling in Lavaan package - R

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am trying to use structural equation modelling (SEM) where I would have the final dependent variable which is nominal, thus requiring Choice modelling. Is there a way I can do this choice modelling in lavaan package in R or any other R package for Structural equation modelling

Comment: A related question has been asked at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358680/lavaan-sem-ordinal-and-categorical-variables/372683#comment985916_372683. The accepted answer links to the lavaan homepage (which does not really help to answer the question). My understanding is that lavaan does not support multinomial choice models. The OpenMx package seems to support probit-models - they just seem to be called "threshold models" (see e.g. here: https://vipbg.vcu.edu/vipbg/OpenMx2/docs//OpenMx/2.18.1/_static/Rdoc/mxThreshold.html).